# deprecated covariant return type for virtual

Tags: c++, inheritance, g++, virtual, covariance

hi everyone i get some warnings while compiling my code with codeblocks which don't know what does it mean, should ignore them or that would reflect on my program during its execution

```
\src\..\inc\UTDB_Field.h|56|warning: deprecated covariant return type for 'virtual int* UTDB_intField::get_valField() const'
\src\..\inc\UTDB_Field.h|19|warning: overriding 'virtual void* UTDB_Field::get_valField() const'
```

In fact `virtual void* UTDB_Field::get_valField() const` const is a pure virtual function in UTDB_Field(the base class) and `virtual int* UTDB_intField::get_valField() const` const is the derived's one(UTDB_intField).

i found several explanations of what does co variant return type means but what i understood  is that the return type void* (in my case) is lost and was replaced by int*, for me that is is my goal i want a generic type of return and each derived class will take in charge of its own.

here is my operator== defined in the derived class UTDB_intField:

```
 virtual bool operator==(const UTDB_Field& Field) const
{
     if(this->typeF==(Field.get_typeField()))
      {
           if(this->nameF==(Field.get_nameField()))
           {
                if (this->val== Field.get_valField())
                return true;
                else
                {
                    std::cout<<" val 1: "<<*(this->get_valField())<<" and val2:  "<<*(int*)Field.get_valField() <<" are different"<<std::endl;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
                {
                    std::cout<<" name 1: "<<this->get_nameField()<<" and name 2: "<<Field.get_nameField() <<" are different"<<std::endl;
                    return false;
                }
      }
      else  {
                std::cout<<" type "<<this->typeF<<" and "<<Field.get_typeField() <<" are two incomparable types"<<std::endl;
                return false;
            }
};
```

when i test it with this :

```
string  a="CurrField";
string* val=&a;
int b=5;
int* val2=&b;

std::cout<<"  *Construction*"<<endl;

UTDB_Field* UTField=new UTDB_strField("name",val);

UTDB_Field* UTField2=new UTDB_intField("Currency",val2);

std::cout<<" --------------- "<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"result of comparison "<<(*UTField2==(*UTField))<<endl;
```

i get my message: type int and str are two incomparable types

result of comparison 0

So if the tow Fields have the same type it is OK i know what type i have, but if they doesn't i should have the message of incompatibility.

any help will be appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't seem to make sense. If they return totally different pointer types, why have them be the same function? How could you use this? Instead of a virtual function with overrides, use `get_intvalField` for `UTDB_intField`. You gain nothing from the polymorphism. (Or make none of the functions virtual and type cast the object instead of the return value.)

Comment: i need to use a generic object as UTDB_Field and if i want to get its value i don't know which type he has so i made it that way and what do you mean by "_Or make none of the functions virtual and type cast the object instead of the return value_" sorry am not experiment in c++

Comment: How can you get its value though? If you don't know what type it is, how do you know what kind of pointer you got back? It seems to me like you created a function that you cannot use. The right way to fix it depends on how you want to use it. I don't understand how you intended this to work, so it's hard for me to tell you precisely how to fix it. What would you normally do with the `void *` that the base function returns? Do you only call the base class' function from derived classes? If so, it should be a different function name and it should be protected.

Comment: I need in my derived class to overload operator== with this prototype **virtual bool operator==(const UTDB_Field& Field) const** (compare this class with another derived from the base)so i need to get its value

Comment: like that: `   UTDB_Field* UTField=new UTDB_intField("name",val2);


    UTDB_Field* UTField2=new UTDB_strField("Currency",val2);
    

    std::cout<<" --------------- "<<std::endl;
     
     
    std::cout<<"result of comparaision "<<(*UTField2==(*UTField))<<endl;`

Comment: What do you want that comparison to do exactly? If the int is 2 and the string is "2", are they equal or not? You should code what you want, but this function won't help you, since you won't know what pointer type you got back, so you won't be able to do anything with it.

Comment: i want to compare 2 objects of UTField either equal or not, there is my function `virtual bool operator==(const UTDB_Field& Field) const
 {if(this->typeF==(Field.get_typeField()))
          {if(this->nameF==(Field.get_nameField()))
               {if (this->val== Field.get_valField())
                    return true;
                    else return false;
                } else return false; 
          } else  return false;
    };
 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting aside design considerations and opinions, the only real problem here is that you are outside the standard and it won't compile with other compilers.  The reason is that the standard only allows return types to differ by covariance. In other words the return type from an overload must be the same type as the base method; or a derived type that implicitly casts to the base. This assumes returns are by pointer/ref.

The intent of covariant return types (typically) was so that class A could have a method that returned a 'A *' from some routine.  Class B derives from A and overloads that methods, but would really like to return a 'B *'. Sure it can say it returns an 'A *' since that is a 'B *', but you'd like the extra info.

This way if someone is using an object of type B and it's known to be B, it can leverage the knowledge that the method is returning (at least) a B* without having to upcast.

What you've done here is awkward, but logically fine.  If you use the object as a UTDB_Field* the method is giving you a void* that could be anything. If you use it as a UTDB_IntField*, which it hopefully really is, then you have the extra info from the prototype that what's being returned is more than a void *, and is indeed an int*.

I won't go into if this is good or bad, but it may be important for you to know about the portability problem taking this to other compilers.

Comment: thank you for your time, it's really clear, but my goal here is not returning(get_valField) a ref of my object i want simply return a pointer to the value of my Field (int*,string*,float* ...),I tested the code, it works, even my operator== give the wanted result if i compare a intField with a strField,my fear here is that warning is really serious and i should remove it or it's ok since I get what I want.

Comment: @oumaya: Red alert! Never do that. Seriously, that's an absolute no no. "I wrote some code that I don't understand or that breaks the rules, but it happens to do what I want when I tested it." It may, for example, break on the next version of the compiler or with another compiler. This will get you in trouble. If you explain what behavior you're actually trying to get (see my comments about how your `operator==` is supposed to work or how you use the pointer) we can tell you the legal way to do it.

Comment: thanks @ David Schwartz am really embarrassed, i don't know what to do, I edited my question to make it clearer, am really confused should I replace all of that by only one class UTDB_Field that use a template(`template<typename MyType>`) for the type of my Field and replace my `void*` by `MyType*` ?